# Append values in json file at specific place and save without overwrite C#

Tags: c#, json.net, append, overwrite

I have to add some values at json file. I don't want to overwrite my file because may be it can be huge.

I add my element like this :

```
foreach (JToken child in logs.Children())
{
     var propertyTable = child as JProperty;

     // Si table existe dans les logs
     if (propertyTable != null && propertyTable.Name == table)
     {
         foreach (JToken grandChild in child)
         {
              var final = grandChild as JProperty;

              // Si field existe dans les logs
              if (grandChild[nameField] != null)
              {
                  grandChild[nameField].AddAfterSelf(dicoDateMsg);
              }
              else
              {
                  child.AddAfterSelf(dicoDateMsg);
              }
          }
      }
}
```

Have you any idea for just write at specific position in json file ?

Thx

Comment: No, you can't just insert data into the middle of a file - regardless of language or content, that's basically just not how file systems typically work.

Comment: Ok thx ! I hope the write his fast.